# Cannot save data:image/jpeg;base64

Tags: javascript, php, android, image

I have this code that displays a color converted image for a customer on the web page, the customer can then click a download button to download the image,
It works fine on a PC but if i try to download the image on a android phone i get the error "Can only download http or https urls"
im guessing its because the saved image has a path like "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD//gA8Q1JFQVRPU"
how do i get this working? does it need to be converted or something?
here is my code:

```html
imagejpeg($gd,NULL,100);
$outputBuffer = ob_get_clean();
$base64 = base64_encode($outputBuffer);
echo '<a id="downloadimage" style="text-decoration:none;" download>
 <img id="image2" style="border:1px solid lightgrey;" width="300" height="400" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.$base64.'" />
 <li style="padding-top:10px;textalign:center;display:block;border-radius:10px;background-color:royaleblue;height:30px;width:100px;background-color: lightgray;
padding-left: 30px;margin-left: 80px;">download</li></a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Well base64 encoded data represents the actual content of image in binary format and cannot be used with img tag. You need to either give the actual path where it is stored locally in the phone as in "../../file.jpg" or in the cloud as in "http://www.google.com/happy.png."